# MongoDB error as setup Wizard ended prematurely, while installing it on windows 10

Tags: node.js, database, windows, mongodb, server

I have downloaded MongoDB from the official site as an `.msi` file and during installation it stops and freezes and after half an hour, and gives an error as the setup wizard ended prematurely.

[image: screenshot of error screen link]

I have a fresh installation of Windows 10 Pro (64-bit) installed just today, and there are no other applications which should be interfering with MongoDB.

I have NodeJS (v8.10.0), npm(5.6.0) installed properly
Windows firewall is turned off and there is no antivirus running.

Is this problem of any missing drivers or any change in BIOS settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too and solve it in this way:

- Remove the older version of MongoDB if you have installed it before.
- Disable your antivirus if you have any of them
- Go to C:>users>"UserName">AppData>Local>Temp
- Right Click on Temp and go to Properties
- Select Security Tab
- Select the User and check the permission and controll give the user full control by Checking Full Control on permission
- Go Ahead and Install MongoDB.

Note that if you want to install MongoDB compass too, you should have internet connection.

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 20):

For me unchecking `Install Compass` helped ...

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. It makes sense to keep it as an answer if it is a working solution.

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed my installation.

Comment: Yes, this is should be the solution. If Compass is desired, after mongodb got installed, browse C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin (replace 3.6 with the installed version), find InstallCompass.ps1, open it, there's a link inside the file that shows the URL of Compass installer. Download and then run it to install Compass.

Answer (score 9):

I disabled installing the router (mongos) and bundeled software client (MongoDB Compass) and installer ran fine after that. Hope this helps.