# Node.js not installing on Windows 10 April update

Tags: node.js, windows-10

I'm trying to install [node-v8.11.2-x64.msi](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on Windows 10 (April update) 64 bit but it's getting Rollback.
I've tried restarting the laptop.
I've tried installing it from [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org)

but no luck.

[image]

I think it has something to do with the admin privileges but I'm already the admin of the windows account.

Comment: Anything in event logs?

Comment: where to find the event logs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220245/mongodb-error-as-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely-while-installing-it-on-windows probably duplicate

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/264

Comment: @Alex i dont have mongoDB though disabling avast solved the issue